# Point and figure chart with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a [point and figure chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPoint%26Figure.GIF).  I can get it to work printing out on the terminal but I want to graph it with matplotlib.  What would be the best way of doing something like this?  I was thinking scatter, but when I do this the columns are spread out too far.  I would like to get something much like the chart from the link I provided where the columns are as close to one another as possible. Is there a parameter I can overwrite to force this?  First time using matplotlib so please excuse me if this is trivial.  Thanks.

Comment: If Jeff is listening over here, you said you have successfully printed the P&F chart on terminal. Would you pl. share the python code (or at least the logic)? I am trying to develop the P&F chart in Python. If it can be printed out in terminal, I will try to take it to HTML format. Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever get a working point and figure chart plotted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can adjust the size of the symbols used in a scatter plot by choosing the `s` [parameter](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter). You also will likely need to adjust the size of your figure (with [figsize](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure)) or the dimensions of your axes (with [add_axes](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)). This is because the symbols for scatter are square, in display units, and the x and y axis are not automatically adjusted so that width-of-one-change = height-of-one-box.

In other words, the example you provided is a rectangular plot with the height > width, and the height and width are chosen to make the width-of-one-change == height-of-one-box.

Here's an example of apply these techniques:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BOX = 5
START = 365
changes = (8, -3, 4, -4, 12, -3, 7, -3, 5, -9, 3)

# one way to force dimensions is to set the figure size:
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 10))

# another way is to control the axes dimensions
# for axes to have specific dimensions:
#                  [ x0,  y0,   w,   h]  in figure units, from 0 to 1
#ax = fig.add_axes([.15, .15, .7*.5, .7])
ax = fig.add_axes([.15, .15, .7, .7])

def sign(val):
    return val / abs(val)

pointChanges = []
for chg in changes:
    pointChanges += [sign(chg)] * abs(chg)

symbol = {-1:'o',
           1:'x'}

chgStart = START
for ichg, chg in enumerate(changes):
    x = [ichg+1] * abs(chg)
    y = [chgStart + i * BOX * sign(chg) for i in range(abs(chg))] 
    chgStart += BOX * sign(chg) * (abs(chg)-2)
    ax.scatter(x, y,
               marker=symbol[sign(chg)],
               s=175)   #<----- control size of scatter symbol

ax.set_xlim(0, len(changes)+1)
fig.savefig('pointandfigure.png')
plt.show()
```

The method developed for each scatter plot is very hackish, but the key point is that I needed to play with the scatter `s` parameter and the figure size to get something of the desired effect.

The resulting plot is:

[image]

Ideally, one would make a custom method modeled after the scatter method. It would create a custom `Collection` [instance](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection) that would include the x's, o's and month labels. It would also a) automatically adjust the axes/figure aspect or b) make asymmetric symbols. This is obviously an advanced option, intended for someone wishing to contribute, as a developer, to the Matplotlib project.

Comment: Nice job!  When I run your code stand alone, each of the columns is a different color, but your example has black x's and blue o's.  How do I force the colors?

Comment: Hello
I'm trying to assemble a "Point and figure" chart
Your answer clarified a lot how I should start, however I found some situations that I need to solve:

1 - The colors I solved and answered below but I thought my answer was ugly.
2 - The dimensions of the graph are not scalable, that is, if I insert a value of 100 in my tuple or list named "changes" the graph loses its shape precisely because of its dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the colors was the best I could.

```
chgStart = START
colors=['red','black','green','blue']

for ichg, chg in enumerate(changes):
     x = [ichg+1] * abs(chg)
     y = [chgStart + i * BOX * sign(chg) for i in range(abs(chg))]
     chgStart += BOX * sign(chg) * (abs(chg)-2)
     ax.scatter(x, y,
            marker=symbol[sign(chg)],
            s=175, color = colors[int(sign(chg))] ) #<----- control size     of scatter symbol
```